# How to solve derivative of definite integral when f(v(x)) = 0?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, chain-rule

I have a question to find the derivative of a definite integral function

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{y}^{x} (t-y)g(t) dt$$

The answer is given

$$(x-y)g(x) - \frac{dy}{dx}\int_{y}^{x} g(t) dt$$

As I found that from this answer [Derivative of definite integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716596/derivative-of-definite-integral)

The chain rule for such a function is
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{y=u(x)}^{x=v(x)} f(t)dt &= \frac{dF}{du}\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{dF}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx} \\&=-f(u(x)) \cdot u'(x) + f(v(x))\cdot v'(x).
\end{align}

In this answer, I don't understand why
$$\frac{dF}{du}$$ become $$-f(u(x))$$

By using this answer, where my function
$$f(t) = (t-y)g(t)$$

As I substituted y into f(t) in my case, the y cancel out. How can I get the right hand part in the given answer.

Comment: Do you assume that $f(t)$ is continuous and $y(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: @Adayah Yes, I assume f(t) is continuous and y(x) is differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation here is a bit more complicated. You can't use the formula for

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int \limits_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t$$

because in your case $f(t) = (t-y) g(t)$ also depends on $y(x)$ (which depends on $x$), making the formula invalid.

The right approach is to consider the function

$$G(u, v, y) = \int \limits_u^v (t-y) g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = \int \limits_u^v t g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t - y \int \limits_u^v g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t.$$

We compute partial derivatives:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}(u, v, y) & = -(u-y) g(u) & \text{because } g \text{ is continuous} \\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}(u, v, y) & = (v-y) g(v) & \text{because } g \text{ is continuous} \\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(u, v, y) & = -\int \limits_u^v g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t & \text{because } F \text{ is linear w.r.t. } y
\end{align*}$$

All the partial derivatives are continuous functions of $(u, v, y)$ hence we can use the chain formula:

$$\begin{align*} 
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} G( u(x), v(x), y(x) ) & = \frac{\partial G}{\partial u}(u, v, y) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}(u, v, y) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(u, v, y) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \\
& = -(u-y) g(u) \cdot u'(x) + (v-y) g(v) \cdot v'(x) - y'(x) \cdot \int \limits_u^v g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t. 
\end{align*}$$

When we substitute $u = y, v = x$, the first term cancels out, so we finally get

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int \limits_y^x (t-y) g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = (x-y) g(x) - y'(x) \cdot \int \limits_y^x g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t.$$

Comment: That is very interesting, thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: There I have a little confusion. Is $\frac{d}{du}\int_{v(u)}^u f(t)dt = f(u)$? Does this method also work for $\frac{d}{du}\int_{v(u,y)}^u yf(t)dt$?

Comment: No, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} \int \limits_{v(u)}^u f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = f(u)$$ may not hold. But in my solution the variables $u, v, y$ of the function $G$ are independent at first when partial derivatives are computed. Their dependence, e.g. $u = y = y(x)$, is taken into account later in the chain rule.

Comment: Intuitively, when $x$ changes a tiny bit $\mathrm{d} x$, then all three values $u(x), v(x), y(x)$ (here $u = y, v = x$, but it's irrelevant to the explanation) change by $\mathrm{d} x$ times $u'(x), v'(x), y'(x)$ respectively. Multiplying each change, e.g. $\mathrm{d} u$, by the contribution it has to the change of $G$, which is $\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}$, gives the component of the change of $G$ cause by the change of $u$. Summing them up gives the total change of $G$.